# How can I configure my iPad so that it doesn't stop uploads after getting auto-locked?

Tags: ipad, data-transfer, ipados

I'm trying to upload a file to Google Drive and SendAnywhere, which would take over an hour. However, I [cannot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/415979/20338) disable auto-lock on my iPad (iPadOS 13) (the maximum auto-lock period is 15 minutes), and whenever the iPad gets locked, uploads are stopped.  How can I configure my iPad so that it doesn't stop uploads after getting auto-locked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no setting like that to configure.

You can ensure that your iPad is not set to Low Power Mode (check in Settings > Battery).

Besides that, the rest is up to the app developer.

Answer (score 1):

Run another app that will prevent sleep.

SatNav apps would be good for this.

Make sure you've got enough power, of course, or are plugged in.